# Perl Regex on a mechanize->content page

Tags: regex, perl

I am fiddling around in perl and I managed to retrieve a HTML page from a source. However I just want to retrieve 1 particulair line. The line starts with a date formatted as follow: dd/mm/YYYY. 
The HTML is in displayed with print $resp->content(); $resp being a response from a $mechanice->submit_form(); 
This is where the resp is made:

```
my $resp = $m->submit_form( 
//bunch of data
},
);
```

How do I achieve this? I am familiar with PHP but I just started with Perl.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example from some Mechanize code that I have.

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get("url that takes you to the page with the form");
$mech->submit_form(form_name => 'someform',
                   fields    => {'user_name' => 'user's
                                 'password'  => 'password'},
                   button    => 'submit');

return if not $mech->success();

my $content = $mech->content();
if ($content =~ m|(\d{2,2}/\d{2,2}/\d{4,4}.*)|g) {
  print "My line: $1\n";
}
```

Comment: It seems to work, I have a follow up question, How do i manage to put a variable called $yesterday with the dd/mm/YYYY format as well (string, i believe) as "some regex" ?
Thanks for your effort so far!

Comment: Sorry forgot that part. The regex would look like: `m|(\d{2,2}/\d{2,2}/\d{4,4}.*)|`

Comment: No problem, ehm... where is the regex? I just see a colon xD

Comment: Wanted to add a new line and it added the comment.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand the regex, do you mind explaining what you are doing?
It does work though, many thanks!

Comment: \d matches one digit. \d{2,2} says to match a min and max of two digits. So it will match dates like 00,01,etc. If the date isn't 0 padded then you want to change it to \d{1,2}. So it matches the day, month, year and then anything (.*) after it. The parentheses capture everything that it matches and sticks it in $1. Does that help?

Comment: Sorry to bother you agian but is there a way to reconize all dates in the file? It just fetches the first it can find which was fine at first but now I'm required to get all dates in the content.

Comment: No problem. I would try splitting the content on new lines and loop on each line. For ex: `my @lines = split("\n", $content); 
foreach my $line (@lines) { if ($line =~ m|regex above|g) { 
  print "$1\n"; 
  } 
}`